# sum of last field

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, sum

I have a trouble to sum fields.
This is what I have: I have list of employees and two rows of values for each, I also have calculations in SQL of running total for the 8 and 16 weeks for each employee for each of two rows using windowing function. I have to group employees by branches they work and calculate sum of running totals for the last 8 and 16 weeks for each row and then device row 1 by row 2. I need to use Last function, because I only need the running total for the last 8 and 16 weeks. The challenge is to go around and have something like: Sum(Last(Fields!Last116WeekSilk.Value) . this one obviously gives me an error. I have tried to add calculated field to the dataset with both Sum and Last functions, doesn’t work, tried RunningValue, doesn’t work. What else can I do to have the sum of last running totals?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please supply a sample dataset and describe exactly how you'd like this data aggregated?

Comment: !http://imgur.com/a/QjgkI

Comment: !http://imgur.com/4aNZoIi

Comment: i posted two links with design and preview images. the pink rows are the two rows that have to have sum of last and the green is the place where i have to place them.

Comment: Not even one answer, no one knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add the SQL ROW_NUMBER function to the query and derive the row number (e.g. 1 or 2) within each group.  If you do this in descending sequence the row number 1 will always be the last row within the group.

Then in SSRS you can use an Iif to only show/calculate on row number 1.

Comment: Thank you! seems such an easy solution, but i have only 6 nested queries inside and 4 of them windowing functions, didnt think something simple will solve it.

Comment: In my experience the SSRS functions should only be used up to a point.  More complex requirements are better met using SQL where you have opportunities to verify the results and debug the query.